# react-rchartjs-2 Radar - dataset with less points than lables

Tags: chart.js

I have a Radar chart with nine labels and within it I'll have three datasets with just three of the nine labels/values each. I need to have three triangles in my chart.

If I just set three values for a given dataset a triangle with first three labels is rendered. What I need is to render the triangle between three other labels (4, 6 and 9 for example).

Thanks guys.

PS: I tried to use `null` in the points I don't want to render but it doesn't work.

PPS: I am using `react-chartjs-2@2.11.1` with `chart.js@2.9.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking on Docs I found the property `spanGaps`. Setting `spanGaps: true` in my dataset graph will ignore my `null` values.